# Oracle: Why are all rows in all my tables duplicated?

Tags: oracle

I am experiencing a strange problem with an Oracle DB, and would like to ask if anyone has experienced a similar problem:

In ALL of my tables (user_tables) EVERY SINGLE row has been duplicated.

What kind of action could have caused such a thing?

Can I restore the previous state without cleaning every table "by hand"?

Comment: what has changed since you had a "normal" db environment? (I assume/hope this was a test env and you were playing around with import or datapump?).  Need more info to nail down the "what kind of action" question (and the "how to restore" question, depends on backups, rman, etc).  Are you a DBA (I assume no)?

Comment: Off the top of my head - "INSERT INTO a_table SELECT * FROM a_table" would do it for a single table.  A little PL/SQL to iterate through all the tables and there's your duplicated data.  Can't say if that's what happened in your case or not.

Comment: It appears to me, the DBA has somehow "screwed up", but I haven't been able to reach him/her yet. I did not use the DB at the time it happened. My fault of course: No constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can imagine many actions which could lead to this situation (for example running imp twice), but it doesn't matter. You should simply prevent such duplicates by means of Unique/Primary keys.

As for restoring previous state you may want to read about flashback query feature:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_fl.htm